# How do I load a Sitecore sublayout automatically so that permissions are respected?

Tags: permissions, sitecore, sublayout

I've created a sublayout (usercontrol) with some simple html. I want to display this sublayout only if the user belongs to a certain role.

If I use the built in sitecore developer center to add the sublayout, I end up with something like

```
  <sc:Sublayout runat="server"
                 RenderingID="{item guid here}" 
                 Path="/layouts/sublayouts/someusercontrol.ascx" 
                 ID="Sublayout1" placeholder="content"></sc:Sublayout>
```

Denying read permission for the sublayout used there has no affect (I assume it's getting loaded because the file path is there right? ). If I take the Path out I get nothing regardless of current user role.

I don't want to manually check if the current user is in the right role from the codebehind. What markup do I use to get the sublayout to consider the user's permissions and determine visibility?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to control sublayout visibility based on a user role in markup. If you dynamically added this sublayout to a placeholder, you could use conditional rendering ("Personalize" button in 6.5) to accomplish this, hiding the component unless the user is a member of a specific role.